# Google Maps is showing grey tiles after publishing the apk in Play Store

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

I work with Google Maps Android API v2 to show some Map Fragments in my App.
Everything works until my App is published in the Play Store (I checked my exported APK before it is published and it worked just fine when sideloaded).

I have an assumption, but first the situation:
I write and sign the app (Also the API Key is from my account).
When the app is ready, another person (with another account in the Play Store) is publishing the App.

Is it possible that the API Key has to be generated from the same account that is publishing the App? I appreciate every hint!!!

My Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.example.android"
android:versionCode="9"
android:versionName="2.2.0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<permission android:name="de.example.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="de.example.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>    

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">

   <!-- GOOGLE MAPS START -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="..." />
   <!-- GOOGLE MAPS END -->

    <activity
        android:name="de.example.android.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="de.example.android.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        >
    </activity>

    <!-- This Activity is called from a lib  -->
    <activity
     android:name="de.example.testlib.android.MapActivity">                            
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the person publishing the app resign the APK with some other keystore?

Comment: Thats a good question...I will check this asap. (But I don't think so, because I would see this while updating the app).

Comment: Your answer was right! The other person resigned the app. Thank you NPike! You helped me really!!!

Answer (score 1):

did you generate a key for the map by using the Keystore and Alias which are used in creation of the publish apk? and after that did you give it to your mapview?

Comment: Yes, I take the same Keystore and Alias. But I don't give my API Key to the MapView. I just add it to my Manifest. My Mapview is a fragment and looks like this: <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

Answer (score 0):

Google generates two keys, one for testing and one for production. Have you change the key to production key before compiling the apk for final release ?